# How many tuples of numbers from [1..n] have the sum of its elements equal to n?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[1..n] is the set of integers from 1 to n. The tuples can be of any finite length. The length of each tuple should range from 1 to n. I am asking how many tuples have elements such that the total sum of the elements is n. For example let's say the set is {1,2,3}. The number of tuples is 4: (1,2), (2,1), (1,1,1), (3).

(Thanks to André Nicolas, for pointing out a bug in an earlier version of this question.)

Comment: Distinct numbers, or maybe not? I assume order matters.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question a bit and added an example. Is it still unclear?

Comment: @FutureTrillionaire No, this is fine now. Thanks! You now get an upvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of ways is $2^{n-1}$. We can show this by induction.

The sequences of numbers chosen from $1,2,\dots,n+1$ that have sum $n+1$ can be divided into two types:

A Type 1 sequence has last entry equal to $1$. It can be obtained from a unique  sequence $S$ with sum $n$ by appending  a $1$ to $S$.

A Type $2$ sequence has last entry $\ge 1$. It can be obtained from a unique sequence $S$ with sum $n$ by adding $1$ to the last entry in the sequence $S$.

Thus if $a_{n}$ is the number of sequences for $n$, then $a_{n+1}=2a_n$.

**Remark:** A sequence of positive integers whose sum is $n$ is called a *Composition* of $n$. For much more detail, please see [this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)

Your list for $3$ was incomplete, for $3$ all by itself is a sequence with sum $3$. If you do not wish to allow sequences of length $1$, the number you are looking for is $2^{n-1}-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'm still confused how you went from a_(n+1) = 2*a_n to 2^(n-1) as the answer.

Comment: +1, very nice answer. @FutureTrillionaire: What is $a_{1}$?

Comment: @AWertheim a1 is just 1, right?

Comment: ...and then a2 is 2*a1. And then a3 is 4*a1. And then a4 is 8*a1...

Comment: Exactly right! :) (This argument is formalized with induction, as André Nicolas notes.)

Comment: Oh, I see the pattern now! So a_n = (2^(n-1))*(1), in which the 1 at the end is a1. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Another way to see that the total number of tuples is $2^{n-1}$ is to imagine $n$ items in a row.  You may then insert or not insert a divider between any two of the items (there are $n-1$ potential insertion points, each with a choice of using or not using a divider).

For example, if $n=5$, you could have $**|*|*|*$ corresponding to the tuple (2, 1, 1, 1).

Comment: I think I understand this. So let the number of potential insertion points be d. The number of dividers that we can insert ranges from 0 to d. The number of ways to insert dividers then is the power set: $2^d$. Since d = n-1, the answer would be $2^{n-1}$.